# How can I add my ExtWebComponent to a JSP?

Tags: extwebcomponents

I would like to add my web components to my JSP. How do I wire up my ExtWebComponents to do this?

My server side runs in a Servlet Container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a project example showing how to do just that. The client side is the ExtWebComponents and a server side is Java.

**Project Notes**

- Maven multi-module project
- Java servlet container on the backend
- The client is an ExtWebComponents project, using the pom.xml only to import it easily as a module into an IDE. And to fire off npm builds.

[Example Project](https://github.com/sencha/sandbox-ewc-public/blob/master/sandbox/)

**JSP Example**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes">

    <title>Sandbox Project</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="resources/favicon.ico">

    <script src="webcomponents-bundle.js"></script>
    <link href="ext/ext.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

Testing
<my-sandbox-view></my-sandbox-view>

<%
    out.write("<h2>Test jsp<h2>");
%>

<!-- The webpacked resource bundle is imported here -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext/ext.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

[Example Source](https://github.com/sencha/sandbox-ewc-public/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-server/src/main/webapp/test-with-ewc.jsp)

**Resources from Client to Server**

You have to tell webpack to copy the resources to your web app directory so they can be used in your Java project. For example this is how it could be done using a custom plugin, and then using webpack --watch.

```
// This causes infinite loop, so I can't use this plugin.
//  new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
//    from: __dirname + '/build/',
//    to: __dirname + '/../sandbox-server/target/test1'
//  }]),

// Inline custom plugin - will copy to the target web app folder
// 1. Run npm install fs-extra
// 2. Fix the path, so that it copies to the server's build webapp folder
{
  apply: (compiler) => {
    compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', (compilation) => {
      // Debugging
      console.log("########-------------->>>>> Finished Ext JS Compile <<<<<------------#######");

      let source = __dirname + '/build/';
      // TODO Set the path to your webapp build
      let destination = __dirname + '/../sandbox-server/target/sandbox';

      let options = {
        overwrite: true
      };
      fs.copy(source, destination, options, err => {
        if (err) return console.error(err)
        console.log('Copy build success!');
      })
    });
  }
}
```

[Example Source](https://github.com/sencha/sandbox-ewc-public/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-client/webpack.config.js)